# Understanding functions forward() and getUnconnectedOutLayers()

Tags: python, opencv

```py
ln = net.getLayerNames()
print(ln)
ln = [ln[i[0]-1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()] 
print(ln)


blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, scalefactor = 1/255.0, size = (416,416), swapRB = True, crop = False)   
net.setInput(blob)
start = time.time()
layerOutputs = net.forward(ln)  
end = time.time()

print("[INFO] Yolo took {:.6f} seconds" .format(end-start))


boxes = []  
confidences = []  
classIDs = []   

for output in layerOutputs :    
    for detection in output :
        scores = detection[5:]  
        classID = np.argmax(scores)
        confidence = scores[classID]

        if confidence > args["confidence"]:
            box = detection[0:4] * np.array([W,H,W,H])
            (centerX, centerY, width, height) = box.astype("int")

            x = int(centerX - (width/2))
            y = int(centerY - (height/2))

            boxes.append([x,y,int(width), int(height)])
            confidences.append(float(confidence))
            classIDs.append(classID)
```

I have two fundamental issues with the code above :

1. I understand that the function `getUnconnectedOutLayers()` is used
   to obtain indexes of the unconnected output layers in order to find
       out how far function `forward()` must run through the network. I
       don't understand why these output layers are denoted as unconnected.
   Also, does that mean that in certain cases we wouldn't run our data through the whole network? If so, why? 
   Another thing bugging me about the line in which we use the `getUnconnectedOutLayers()` function is the `ln[i[0]-1` part of it. I believe that is some way of traversing `ln` array in reverse, but I don't fully understand it.
2. In the documentation, it is stated that the function `forward()`
   returns blob for first output of the specified layer. I assume it is the same blob we get from the function `blobFromImage()` in the sense that it is also 4D. 
   Later in the code, the following is stated: `scores
   = detection[5:]`. Since I assumed it is a 4D array, I was expecting the following: `scores = detection[5:::]`. Are the two dimensions
   "dropped" in slicing due to the two for loops?

Answer (score 0):

net.getUnconnectedOutLayers() gives the position of the layers. the output is an ndarray of shape (1,). So to get the integer we do ln[0]. And to get the index we subtract 1 from the position.